# Rails: Get all objects with some condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have a class Equipment, which has a method do decide if the object is available or not.
This method has some logic to check thought a has_many association, and returns true or false, so, it only work in instantiated object.

There is some way to do something like:

```
@someVar = Equipament.all.available
```

I solve this making:

```
equipament.rb

has_many :rents
  def available
    if(self.rents.blank?)
      return true
    else
      if(self.rents.last.end.blank?)
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  def self.usable
    ary = Array.new
    Equipament.all.each do |eq|
      if eq.available
        ary.push(eq)
      end
    end
    return ary
  end
```

And then

```
@someVar = Equipament.usable
```

But, is this a nice way or there are something more efficient/elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the infinite database queries your code could be making, the whole approach is not flexible. There could be many other reasons why the `Equipment` wouldn't be `available` other than `rents`. It could be in maintenance for example. That would mean making the `available` method even more complicated. Therefore, I believe defining a `state` for the `Equipment` would be much easier to maintain. You would change the `Equipment.state` based on certain events. In your case, you can change the `Equipment.state` to `rented` whenever someone rent it, and change it back to `available` whenever it gets returned. Not only you could now cover many more cases, but you will be also able to get a list of all available equipment with a simple method which fires only one query to the database:

```
# models/equipament.rb

def self.available
  where(state: :available)
end
```

Comment: But it wold require another field in the database, and i wold have to maintain it properly, right?

Comment: @Techmago it is not possible to make an informed opinion since I don't know the full context of your case. However, in general, maintaining an extra field in the database seems like a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: yes i think in the end, that would be the best option. I always made effort to minimize at all costs the number of fields in the database... 
The best option i found is to use the state machine gem to handle those states, which allow me to add more states later

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
equipament.rb

has_many :rents
def available
  (self.rents.blank? && !self.rents.last.end.blank?) ? true : false
end

def self.usable
  ary = Array.new
  Equipament.all.each do |eq|
    if eq.available
      ary.push(eq)
    end
  end
  return ary
end
```